# Check condition of data frame with corresponding vector

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Let's create some artificial data and their 0.99 quantiles.

```
set.seed(42)
x = data.frame("Norm" = rnorm(100),
               "Unif" = runif(100),
               "Exp" = rexp(100))

quants <- apply(x, 2, quantile, 0.99)
```

I want to check **without loop** which elements of the variables are bigger than 0.99 quantile.

So first variable should be compared with first element of `quants`, second with second and third with third.

Intuitively I used: `x > quants` and it's good that I checked the outcome, because R seems to interpret this command as something else.

```
e.g. 

> head(x > quants)
      Norm  Unif   Exp
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

As you can see third element of Exp should signalize that it's bigger than 0.99 quantile. However:

```
> x[3, ][3] > quants[3] 
    Exp
3 FALSE
```

Gives false. Do you know how can I fix this problem ? I tried to play with apply but wasn't sure how to use it properly in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this, Here x is your dataframe, quants the value from which you want comparision and function applied is greater than symbol. Sweep applied here on column wise hence 2:

```
sweep(x, 2,STATS=quants, `>`)
```

Comment: That's a good one! However - how would you specify in which `sweep` function exactly in which quantile we are interested ? e.g. 0.99

Comment: @John I am not sure if I understood you well but don't you have `quants` already calculated with you atleast that is what you have mentioned.

Comment: This seems to be the most concise answer, and is in base R as OP requested.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `purrr::map2_df`.

```
# there are two objects I am iterating
# x data.frame is referenced as .x
# quants vector is referenced as .y
purrr::map2_df(x, quants, ~ .x > .y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do you really think that external package has to be used to do that ?

Comment: I think you can do it in base R as well. It is just that I am more familiar with purrr syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following code might help you get your desired output:

```
library(purrr)

set.seed(42)
x = data.frame("Norm" = rnorm(100),
               "Unif" = runif(100),
               "Exp" = rexp(100))

quants <- apply(x, 2, quantile, 0.99)

map2_dfr(x, quants, ~ .x > .y)

# A tibble: 100 x 3
   Norm  Unif  Exp  
   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE
 2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
 3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
 4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
 5 FALSE FALSE FALSE
 6 FALSE FALSE FALSE
 7 FALSE FALSE FALSE
 8 FALSE FALSE FALSE
 9 FALSE FALSE FALSE
10 FALSE FALSE FALSE
# ... with 90 more rows
```

And here is another easy way if you want to stick to base R:

```
head(mapply(function(x, y) x > y, x, quants)) 

      Norm  Unif   Exp
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Ok I didn't notice the first answer posted by dear @Jakub. Novotny as I was typing my own. They are basically the same but he deserves credit.

Comment: I took the .x > .y instead of `>`(.x, .y) from your answer to be honest. I did not know you can do it without backticks. Upvoted yours.

Comment: Oh thank you very much I thought you were the one who asked the question at first. That's my pleasure and I am so sorry to post a similar answer to yours. And thank you for your vote you deserve it more. The reason I used `.x >.y` is that it is the purrr style lambda which is using formula interface to define a function and it will be converted to function by `as_mapper`. You can also type the formula into it and check it for yourself : `as_mapper(~ .x > .y)` just run it into your console to see how it is interpreted as function.

Comment: I believe `purrr` is full of wonders and every time I read the documentations, I learned something new. In my opinion it is the second most complicated package after `rlang`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually when checking `x > quants` R checks it columnwise instead of rowwise.  First element of first row is checked with first quants, first element of second row is checked with second quants and so on.  Hence when checking x[3,3], it is actually 203rd element in this iteration and is thus checked with second element of quants `(203 %% 3 = 2)`.  That's you're getting an error.

Also see

```
colSums(x > quants)

Norm Unif  Exp 
   4    0   19
```

which locates the error in given syntax.